# making calculator with antlr

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

am very new to using antlr. I am making a calculator and I have already made my grammar. is it possible to get results if I use listener instead of visitor? I don't know if that makes sense but I am using the listener and the only thing I have been able to do is to get it to print out the input but not the calculated result from the input. I have checked online and every example uses the visitor. so should I use visitor or is there someway you can get results when using listener? I hope that makes sense.

this is my g4 file

```
grammar calc;

TYPE_INT: 'int';
TYPE_FLOAT: 'float';
EQU: '=';
MUL: '*';
DIV: '/';
PLU: '+';
MIN: '-';
L_BKT: '(';
R_BKT: ')';
WRITE: 'write';
END_MARK: ';';
ID: ([A-Z]|[a-z]) ([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9])*;
INT: ('0'|([1-9]([0-9])*));
FLOAT: ('0'|([1-9]([0-9])*))'.'([0-9]+)(('e'|'E')('+'|'-')?('0'|([1-9]([0-
9])*)))? ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

declare: (typeInt=TYPE_INT|typeFloat=TYPE_FLOAT) id=ID;
assign: id=ID equ=EQU expr;
expr: expr (plu=PLU|min=MIN) expr2|expr2;
expr2: expr2 (mul=MUL|div=DIV) expr3 |expr3;
expr3: floatNumber=FLOAT| intNumber=INT| id=ID| lBkt=L_BKT expr rBkt=R_BKT;
writeFunction: write=WRITE lBkt=L_BKT id=ID rBkt=R_BKT;

stmt: declare| assign| writeFunction;
stmts: (stmt endMark=END_MARK)*;
r: stmts;
```

this is the variable and variableList class I made to use in calcbaseListener

```
public class Variable {
public String name="";
public String type="int";
public float value=(float) 0.0;

}


public class VariableList {

List<Variable> list=new ArrayList();

private static VariableList self=new VariableList();

public static VariableList getList(){
    return self;
}

public Variable find(String name){
    Variable v=null;
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        Variable tmp=list.get(i);
        if(tmp.name.equals(name)){
            v=tmp;
        }
    }
    return v;
}

public void add(Variable v){
    list.add(v);
}

}
```

this is the code I put in calcBaseListener

```
    public void exitDeclare(calcParser.DeclareContext ctx) {
    String name=ctx.id.getText();
    Variable v=new Variable();
    v.name = name;

    if(ctx.typeFloat != null) {
        v.type = "float";
    } else {
        v.type = "int";
    }

    VariableList list = VariableList.getList();

    if(list.find(v.name) == null) {
        list.add(v);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The id has already been declared");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


    public void exitAssign(calcParser.AssignContext ctx) {
    String name = ctx.id.getText();
    VariableList list = VariableList.getList();

    if(list.find(name) == null) {
        System.out.println("Undeclared id");
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        Variable v = list.find(name);
        if(v.type.equals(ctx.expr().v.type) || v.type.equals("float") && 
        ctx.expr().v.type.equals("int")) {
            v.value = ctx.expr().v.value;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The type of int assigned to the type of type 
            of float error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    } 
}


    public void exitExpr(calcParser.ExprContext ctx) {
    if(ctx.expr()==null){
        if(ctx.v.type.equals(ctx.expr2().v.type)||
            ctx.v.type.equals("float")&&ctx.expr2().v.type.equals("int")){
            ctx.v.value=ctx.expr().v.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("The type of int assign to the tpye of float 
             error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ctx.v.value=ctx.expr().v.value;
        return;
    }
    if(ctx.plu!=null){
        String type="";
        if(ctx.expr().v.type.equals("float")
                ||ctx.expr2().v.type.equals("float")){
            type="float";
        }else{
            type="int";
        }
        if(ctx.v.type.equals(type)||
                ctx.v.type.equals("float")&&type.equals("int")){
            ctx.v.value=ctx.expr().v.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("The type of int assign to the tpye of float 
             error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ctx.v.value=ctx.expr().v.value+ctx.expr2().v.value;
        return;
    }
    if(ctx.min!=null){
        String type="";
        if(ctx.expr().v.type.equals("float")
                ||ctx.expr2().v.type.equals("float")){
            type="float";
        }else{
            type="int";
        }
        if(ctx.v.type.equals(type)||
                ctx.v.type.equals("float")&&type.equals("int")){
            ctx.v.value=ctx.expr().v.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("The type of int assign to the tpye of float 
            error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ctx.v.value=ctx.expr().v.value-ctx.expr2().v.value;

        return;
    }

}



   public void exitExpr2(calcParser.Expr2Context ctx) {
    if(ctx.expr2()==null){
        if(ctx.v.type.equals(ctx.expr3().v.type)||
                ctx.v.type.equals("float")&&ctx.expr3().v.type.equals("int")){
                    ctx.v.value=ctx.expr2().v.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("The type of int assign to the tpye of float error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ctx.v.value=ctx.expr2().v.value;
        return;
    }
    if(ctx.mul!=null){
        String type="";
        if(ctx.expr2().v.type.equals("float")
                ||ctx.expr3().v.type.equals("float")){
            type="float";
        }else{
            type="int";
        }
        if(ctx.v.type.equals(type)||
                ctx.v.type.equals("float")&&type.equals("int")){
            ctx.v.value=ctx.expr2().v.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("The type of int assign to the tpye of float error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ctx.v.value=ctx.expr2().v.value*ctx.expr3().v.value;
        return;
    }
    if(ctx.div!=null){
        String type="";
        if(ctx.expr2().v.type.equals("float")
                ||ctx.expr3().v.type.equals("float")){
            type="float";
        }else{
            type="int";
        }
        if(ctx.v.type.equals(type)||
                ctx.v.type.equals("float")&&type.equals("int")){
            ctx.v.value=ctx.expr2().v.value;
        }else{
            System.out.println("The type of int assign to the tpye of float error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ctx.v.value=ctx.expr2().v.value/ctx.expr3().v.value;
        return;
    }
}


    public void exitExpr3(calcParser.Expr3Context ctx) {
    if(ctx.floatNumber!=null){
        ctx.v.type="float";
        ctx.v.value=Float.valueOf(ctx.floatNumber.getText());
    }
    if(ctx.intNumber!=null){
        ctx.v.type="int";
        ctx.v.value=Float.valueOf(ctx.intNumber.getText());
    }
    if(ctx.id!=null){

        VariableList list=VariableList.getList();
        String name=ctx.id.getText();
        ctx.v.type=list.find(name).type;
        ctx.v.value=list.find(name).value;
    }

    if(ctx.expr()!=null){
        ctx.v.type=ctx.expr().v.type;
        ctx.v.value=ctx.expr().v.value;
    }
}


 public void exitWriteFunction(calcParser.WriteFunctionContext ctx) {
    VariableList list=VariableList.getList();
    String name=ctx.id.getText();
    if(list.find(name)!=null){
        Variable v=list.find(name);
        System.out.println(v.value);

    }else{
        System.out.println("Undecleared id");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

is it possible for me to get value of a calculation if i write my code like this?

Comment: You need to show us what your grammar and how your current code look like. Normally it should be possible to use visitors if you got the precedence right in your grammar

Comment: @Raven I have edited it to put the grammar and code.

Comment: If you are using left-recursion anyway why didn't you use it to declare the `expr` and all `expr1,2,3` in one single rule?

Comment: I don't know I just did. am very new at this. is it wrong the way I did?

Comment: It's not wrong but it makes things more complicated than they need to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer your orignal question: Yes it is possible to implement a calculator using a listener.

At this point  will simply refer to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/ouyi/antlr4calc) that provides both: One implementation using a listener and one using a visitor.

As the above referenced grammar can't handle assignments I'D suggest to have a look at [this repo](https://github.com/shmatov/antlr4-calculator) as well that does provide the assignment-functionality next to the pure arithmetic-parsing. Note though that this one does not take advantage of ANTLR's capability to deal with direct left-recursion which leads to a lot more code for the same task.

In general I'd advise you to do take advantage of direct left-recursive rules as tehy make your grammar a lot simpler to read. In combination alternative-rule-labeling it's a real powerful feature.

Answer (score 0):

Please find an example of a antlr4 based [calculator](https://github.com/RobertPastor/calculator/blob/master/README.md).

The grammar are very similar. However I would strictly follow the recommendation expressed by Raven and group all the "algebraic precedence stuff" in one antlr4 rule. Doing so will insure that precedence is respected as antlr4 will explore (without braces) the multiply divide part of an expression before the additive and substraction.

I did use a visitor. A visitor is definitely the best place to manage the computation of results. Visitors are built to return results. Listeners are not returning results.
The proposed implementation is written in python. The visitor creates a dictionary with keys being the name of the variables found on the left hand side of the equality. Each time an operator is triggered in the visitor, we ask for the operands, compute the results according to the kind of operation and store the resulting value in the dictionary for the variable.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with particularly ANTLR 4, but in general - making a calculator means you need to consider not individual tokens / terms, but you also need to consider their relationships and position in the parse tree (e.g. to process addition, you need to also access the operands).

Visitor seems to be a more suitable approach (since there you decide in which order and in what manner to visit the nodes) rather than listener (when is the listener invoked? Are you certain the needed children of the parse tree are already processed and accessible to you?)