# What is the best way to implement a "calculator"?

Tags: performance, optimization, calculator, infix-notation

I am a Computer Science new blood and I want to make a fast calculator.

I've already done one by converting infix to postfix, a calculate sequentially.
I've considered expression tree but the input might not be well-parenthesesed.

So I was wondering, is there any other way to implement a calculator. PS: Both binary and unary might exist.

Comment: one way is to use parser generator like Antlr or bison with simple grammar to generate AST from input
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094546/making-calculator-with-antlr

Comment: "input might not be well-parenthesesed." in that case the input is wrong. I don't see what that has to do with expression tree.